# List events tracking Analytics Reporting API v4

Tags: reporting, google-analytics-api

I am trying to list all custom events I have tracked with this code :

```
gtag('event', 'view-video-x');
```

With reporting API php, I have this code :

```
$analytics->data_ga->get('ga:' . $this->id, $start->format('Y-m-d'), $end->format('Y-m-d'), 'ga:totalEvents,ga:uniqueEvents'), array('dimensions' => 'ga:eventAction', 'filters' => 'ga:eventCategory==general')
```

But the results is not like expected :

```
public 'rows' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '10' (length=2)
          1 => string '2' (length=1)
```

It gives me the total but I want the list like Query Explorer :

[image]

Thank you per advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `dimensions` are not merged properly (`get()` merges first arrray with second one)

But this one-liner code here is not properly formatted, so pls reformat it properly (this above would throw Exception so c/p from your code should work).
And make it a block code, dont do one-liners, its difficult to read it properly.

Since i cannot comment, ill delete this *answer* once you see it as it is not an answer.

Comment: Thank you @CT., I reformated my code and I saw that the fifth parameter of get() (dimensions parameter) where not in the right place.